# Excel If Else Statement For Copying Data with Checkboxes

Tags: excel, if-statement, checkbox, copy

I would like to set up some code for copying some cells with check boxes

I have 30 checkboxes

I have copied the code below and modified it 30times

This is no doubt redundant

Each check box is on a row, the data it will copy is on the same row

When the checkbox is clicked the row data in the next cell will be copied and moved somewhere else

This data will be dumped somewhere below in the same worksheet

I tried creating the elseif statements, unfortunately they did not work

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 2").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
     Range("f2").Select
     Selection.Cut
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     Range("f15").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Range("f15").Select
     Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown    
     End If
     End Sub

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 3").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
     Range("f3").Select
     Selection.Cut
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     Range("f15").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Range("f15").Select
     Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown    
     End If
     End Sub

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 4").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
     Range("f4").Select
     Selection.Cut
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     Range("f15").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Range("f15").Select
     Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown    
     End If
     End Sub
```

It is very repetitive as you can see

Any advice on how I can write this code so it will be like a nested if statement

if checkbox 1 is true do this
if checkbox 2 is true do this
etc etc

[IMG]http://i44.tinypic.com/2db78dj.jpg[/IMG]

please advise thank you

Comment: What is the relationship between the checkbox and the cell(s) on which it should operate?  If you can describe this relationship, it would be easy to consolidate this in to only a few lines of code, instead of 30 `If/Else` statements or a `Select Case` statement.

Comment: Checkboxe shapes should have a TopLeftCell and a BottomRightCell property - that should allow you to work out which row each checkbox is located on.

Comment: I apologise, I can never seem to copy and past code in the right format here, its the first block of code repeated 30 times for 30 checkboxes,when the checkbox is clicked the row data will be copied and moved somewhere else

Comment: I made a slight revision to my answer. Looks like your destination never changes, only the range that you need to cut/paste.  Again, this can probably be streamlined even further if you can describe the arrangement of these checkboxes in relationship to the worksheet structure, or provide a screenshot, etc.  Otherwise, I just make a comparison to the checkbox's `.Name` property within the `Select Case` block, and assign a different `cutRange` for each checkbox.

Comment: Hi David, I added a screenshot, I appreciate your help. I just want to move some data to another part of the worksheet. The worksheet is very slow with 30 macros [IMG]http://i44.tinypic.com/2db78dj.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing a little more about the workbook structure, this is the best I can come up with.  THere is likely some sort of "relationship" between the CheckBoxes and the cell(s) that need to be operated on, which could allow you to use a formula or some other logic to determine the cells to cut/paste, rather than relying on If/Then or Case logic.

```
Sub Test()

Dim cb As Shape
Dim cutRange As Range
'## The destination doesn't change, so we put this outside the loop
'    also make it a constant value:
Cosnt destRange As String = "F15"

'## Now, iterate over each checkbox control in the sheet:
For Each cb In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    '## Make sure the shape is an xlCheckBox AND value = True/checked
    If cb.FormControlType = xlCheckBox And cb.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        '## Assign the cutRange based on the CheckBox name
        Select Case cb.Name
            Case "Check Box 2"
                Set cutRange = Range("F3")
            Case "Check Box 3"
                Set cutRange = Range("F4")
            Case "Check Box 4"
                Set cutRange = Range("F5")
            'etc.

            '## You can add as many Case values as you need
        End Select

        '## One statement cuts & inserts:
        cutRange.Cut Range(destRange)
        Range(destRange).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi David, I think this is what I was trying to create, as you can imagine I had the same code copied 30times, I simply changed the check box number each time. Please let me come back with copying this into a workbook , thank you

Comment: Hi David, destRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown is giving me an error, I'm not sure why, I copied the code exactly and inserted a checkbox into sheet, I added the code as a module is that correct?

Comment: Also when I click on the check box it gives me an error 424  object required

Comment: What's the error message on `destrange.insert`??  Also do you know whether the checkboxes are form controls or ActiveX control?

Comment: Hi David, the error is   424 object required, on the debug mode the destRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown is highlighted. I inserted checkboxes into the form -  they would be form control.  [IMG]http://i42.tinypic.com/14u9j54.png[/IMG]   and [IMG]http://i39.tinypic.com/35aot4o.png[/IMG]

Comment: I think the Cut/Copy is intefering with the existing range object.  Try `Range("F15").Insert Shift:=xlDown`.

Comment: David, you are a fine Sir, thank you very much,I can delete those 30 macros plus 10 others in my excel workbook now, coding like a novice, thank you again for your time :)

Comment: My pleasure! Glad to help you learn a few things -- loops (like this) and efficient use of subroutines can make your code so much easier to maintain and update in the future!